# JSON parsing in NODE

Tags: json, node.js, express, jsonp

I'm trying to figure out why my parsed request(a json from an jquery ajax, cross domain) is looking a bit strange.

```
GET /sendjsondata?callback=_testcb&{%22amount%22:1800,%22name%22:%22Vasy%20Jon%22,%22cnp%22:232323,%22coborrower%22:true,%22device%22:%22Desktop%22}&_=1415883870387 404 3.346 ms - 1303
```

I can create a function to retrieve the piece between braces and then applying a new polish to remove "%22", but I think that I'm dooing a mistake somewhere in my code and that's why I don't obtain a clean json object and maybe someone can tell me where is the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

URLs use a special encoding to represent special characters. `%22` equals `"`. Whatever framework you are using should take care of decoding this. Otherwise look for `urlencode()`/`urldecode()` functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I solved it. I had some issues with the hosting server of my external ajax.